# How I warm my feet in the winter season?

Tags: personal-care, winter

My feet can't warm in socks, shoes, or even under a quilt. I am not feeling well in the winter season because of this problem. How can I warm my feet in winter?

Comment: You will find your answer here:
https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/56/how-can-i-stay-warm-in-subzero-0f-18c-weather?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all start with warm feet. Rub them with your hands throughly to get blood flowing to your feet. If that is ineffective➖put them in a basin of warm water while wiggling your toes. 
Continue in warm water until they feel warm. Dry them off immediately upon removing them from water.

Once dry put on really good wool socks. Merlino wool are the best. They’re expensive but nothing will keep feet as warm. 
[image: socks]
My favorite sock are a brand called [Darn Tough Socks](https://darntough.com/collections/mens-hike-trek). They are pricey but come with a lifetime warranty. If they wear out➖return them for a brand new pair. They are available from the company online or many other retailers.

Finally➖if you have circulation problems you should mention it to your doctor. It could be a sign of an underlying health issue.

Answer (score 1):

Jogging is a one good way, hot tea, warm sweater.

Answer (score 1):

Move your feet around, even if it's just wriggling your toes. Keep your surroundings warm (don't stay outside too long or keep the thermostat too low). Essentially, you need to keep your blood circulating through your feet normally.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering with science. naturally the cold feet means the blood is not enough for the warming process or the measure is too down. so if you had wear sucks, its not from measure!I think its better to check it with a doctor or do a Doppler Ultrasonography. 
*if your feet is cold after you eat food or something in winter, its just safe and normal.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to use bags of wheat kernels heated in the microwave.  Get about 4-6 cups of raw, whole wheat kernels from a bulk grocery store, then sew them up into a flannel bag so they are loose inside.  Microwave them on high for about 2 minutes for each bag (I use 2 bags so 4 minutes for me).  They come out of the microwave toasty warm with moist heat that will last for 20-30 minutes.

They can warm up your feet, or the bottom part of your bed where your feet go, or sit them on your lap while you work at the computer.  They are magical!  They also last many, many re-heatings so they are a permanent solution!

Answer (score 0):

When my feet are impossibly cold, I put them in warm water (or take a warm shower) in order to bring them up to a “normal” temperature. From there, I can use more conventional solutions like warm socks or slippers. Additionally, I recommend a heated blanket for nighttime.

Answer (score 0):

When I was a boy, we used a bit of powdered cayenne pepper in our socks and shoes. It did work to warm our feet; just start off with a little until you get a feel for how much to use.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some things you could do:

- get some warm fuzzy socks as i call them, the ones that are just soo soft and fluffy
- sit in front of a fireplace or other source of heat that is coming torwards you
- put some socks and slippers into your dryer and when they come out they will be super warm
- fill up a bathtub (with hot water of course) and put your feet in there or put them in a hot tub or jacuzzi